How to give space between equation and equation number inside align?
\begin{spreadlines}{0.7em}
\begin{align}
    i_{\text{out}}(t) = \langle i_{\text{out}} \rangle  + i^{\text{HF}}_{\text{out}}(t) &= \Re\big[\vv{s_{d}}\,e^{j\omega_st}\big]\Re\big[\vv{i_{d}}\,e^{j\omega_st}\big] \nonumber \\
    &= \Re\!\left[ \frac{{\vv{s_{d}}}^*}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{{\vv{i_{d}}}}{\sqrt{2}}\right]\!+\Re\!\left[\frac{{\vv{s_{d}}}}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{{\vv{i_{d}}}}{\sqrt{2}}\,e^{2j\omega_st} \right] 
\end{align}
\end{spreadlines}


Welcome to TeX SE. Could you expand your code to make it compilable?

I guess from \vv and \text you're loading esvect and amsmath. I see no spacing problem, actually, so I guess you have something you're not showing, for instance that you're typesetting in two-column format. Some more details are needed.

I suggest you switch from a two-row to a three-row align setup.

This setup will also let you replace the e^{...} terms with \exp(...) terms, for greater legibility.
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % 'twocolumn' is optional
\usepackage{mathtools,esvect}

% handy shortcut macros:
\newcommand\vvid{\vv{i_d}}
\newcommand\vvsd{\vv{s\vphantom{i}_d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadlines}{1ex}
\begin{align}
    i_{\mathrm{out}}(t) 
    &= \langle i_{\mathrm{out}} \rangle  
      + i^{\mathrm{HF}}_{\mathrm{out}}(t)     \notag\\
    &= \Re \bigl[\vvsd\exp(j\omega_s t)\bigr]
       \Re \bigl[\vvid\exp(j\omega_s t)\bigr] \notag\\
    &= \Re\biggl[\frac{{\vvsd}^*}{\sqrt2}
                 \frac{\vvid}{\sqrt2}\biggr]
      +\Re\biggl[\frac{\vvsd}{\sqrt2}  
                 \frac{\vvid}{\sqrt2}
                 \exp(2j\omega_s t)  \biggr] 
\end{align}
\end{spreadlines}

\end{document}

